# Where else can a splash screen come from without a LaunchScreen.storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, splash-screen, launch-screen

What are the different ways to set up a splash screen in Swift?

I have one project in which I am getting the splash screen while executing the project but I don't understand where the splash screen comes from.

I know one way of getting the splash screen is from LaunchScreen.storyboard but in this project there is no splash screen added, even though one is still being shown. I want to know how and where it comes from.

Comment: could you please share your example as a picture, if you set it via IB or some code if you do it programmatically?

Comment: @AlexWoe89 okay i am doing

Comment: Xcode > click Project >  General tab > App Icon and Launch Images > Launch Screen File

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a folder named ‘Splash Screen’ and put your splash image there then it will take the splash screen from there automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the project is using a different storyboard for the Launch Screen.

Check the ‘Launch screen interface file base name’ property in the ‘Info.plist’ file. The value for this key should tell you about the name of the file that contains the Launch Screen.